# How to change font of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, text-editor, spring-tool-suite, font-style

I am switching from IntelliJ to Eclipse(STS) of work reason, but the font is something I am missing in Eclipse. I have googled and found that the font I am looking for "Droid Sans" was present in Eclipse earlier versions but can't find on this on(Spring Tool Suite). Is it still there or I have to import it from outside and set in manually. Also, if importing is possible in Eclipse or not.

Comment: Are you also changing computers? Eclipse will let you pick from the fonts installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to import as isn't there by default. Yes, importing is possible. Can be found under Windows > Preferences > General > Colors and Appearance. Change as you see fit.